# Problems in building apache ant

Tags: java, ant

I am just studing Java and looking for my first job, so I'm not very good in it. Also it's my first post here.

So, I'm trying to read and do exercises from the book Thinking in Java 4th edition(TIJ4). For some exercises you need the code that athour left in one of his Git repositories. Here is the problem. There is a readme file in this repository, it contains instruction how to install code from the book. Everything was fine until paragraph 7:

[descryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtDGu.png)

I installed apache ant, but nothing worked. Than I understood that installing is not enough, and I need to build it. I found manual and tried to do it and failed.

[how to build ant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTUME.png)

I did it and got this:

[building ant 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmh3S.png)

I don't what to do about access.
Also there is another solution in this building guide:

[building ant2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOCqB.png)

But here I don't understand anything.
So, please explain what is that in a last screen, and how to build ant.

Comment: You don't have administrator privileges.

Comment: The instructions look dubious. For one thing, there shouldn't be any need to create directories in privileged locations. From what link did you get the source code (github somewhere presumably)?

Comment: I just found the author of the book on a github. This is readme file in his repository.https://github.com/BruceEckel

Comment: In paragraph 7 there is also stated, that Ant is not required. You can compile the code via the javac command. You can also copy the needed classes to your own project. Think of it as a challenge. if you know how to do it, you've taken a decisive step forward.

Comment: I've managed to start compilation via ant, but it told me that Ineed Java 5. Than I tried compile it via javac and got this error in IntelJ "java: package net.mindview.util does not exist"